# Ubuntu One Music Store Match service?

Tags: ubuntu-one

Does the Ubuntu One team plan to incorporate a service like **[iTunes Match](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITunes_Match#iTunes_Match)** into the Ubuntu One Music Store?

Comment: I tried to read the wikipedia page about iTunes Match, but I just don't understand what it does. Perhaps you should ask about a feature? Someone bragged about the new AirDrop. I didn't know what it was. Turns out it's something Ubuntu has had for many years. Not everyone is used to Apple-English.

Comment: @jo-erland iTunes Match reads your library metadata and allows you to stream matching songs within the iTunes Store, if a song doesn't match you can upload it.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually no need.

https://one.ubuntu.com/services/music/

Stream **your** music, just ask them to make a web app and I think that'd be it! I don't think Canonical could afford the licences in which Apple can afford for the match service anyway.